# MS Access: Using parameters with hyphens in a parameter query

Tags: ms-access

I have serial numbers in the form X-xxxx, where X is an alpha char and x is numeric, I can't seem to get the parameter passed in correctly.

One thing I've tried, which actually works properly in a different database of similar info, is:

```
Like [Enter Serial Number:] & "-*" Or [Enter Serial Number:]
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me you want to allow the users to search 2 ways:

1. enter the full serial number
2. enter only one character (and return all serial numbers which start with that character)

If that's what you're after, try a query like this:

```
PARAMETERS [Enter Serial Number:] Text ( 6 );
SELECT p.*
FROM tblPingPong AS p
WHERE
    (((p.serial_num)=[Enter Serial Number:]))
    OR (((p.serial_num) Like [Enter Serial Number:] & "-*"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking the user for the numeric portion:

```
Like "*-" & [Enter Serial Number:]
```

However, this will be slow unless your table is quite small. You might like to consider getting the input for the query from a form.

Comment: Asking for the whole serial, because some are not in the same format; I don't know why what I have won't work. I've used the same parameter as above for multiple other things and it works fine. Guess it's just another reason to push for something other than access! 

Thanks for your reply though, I do appreciate it.

Comment: If you are asking for the whole serial number, you just need [Enter Serial Number:]

Comment: I do not quite see why you need something else if you cannot get Access to work. What happens when you can't get the new thing to work? :)

Comment: There are multiple things in access and vb that don't work as they do in other databases or programming languages. i've worked with ms sql, mysql and many other variants of sql, never have i had as many issues as i am on this access project. access is too restrictive for my needs.

Comment: All databases and development environments have quirks and dialects for particular tasks. Expecting a new environment to behave like what you're accustomed to is *your* fault, not that of the new environment. In this case, there's nothing at all peculiar to Access's dialect of SQL here that's causing the problem -- it's really that you have bad data. You'd have to do something almost identical with any other SQL dialect. The only differences would be in the wildcard character and, perhaps, the definition of the parameter. So, blaming it on Access is really completely wrongheaded.